# Android: can you access AsyncTask class members in DoInBackground?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-handler

Is it safe to run a method of an `AsyncTask` class member inside the `DoInBackground`? or do you need to use a handler?

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Object mObjA = null:

    private MyAsyncTask(Object objA) {
        mObjA = objA
    }

    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mObjA.aMethod()
    }

}
```

in `doInBackground` is it safe to run `mObjA.aMethod()` if `mObjA` wasn't passed as a parameter? is there a multithreading issue?

should you in `doInBackground` only access objects which have been deliberately passed, or can you freely access any member of the class without using handlers?

Comment: just validate your code. simple.

Comment: the code runs, but I would like to know if it's multithreading-correct without using handlers

Comment: it will throw nullpointerexception. so it's bad i guess :)

Comment: no, it doesn't throw NullPointerException

Comment: @DanieleB: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: hi @ZygoteInit, yes I had read it, thanks. you and ci_ are saying pretty much the same thing. Beyond avoiding UI objects, ci_ is adding that also not thread-safe objects might be troublesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed access any field of your `AsyncTask` inside `doInBackground()`, with the condition that `mObjA` is not a UI-related Android class like `ViewPager` or `LinearLayout` or any sort of `ViewGroup` basically.

Comment: UI classes are the most common culprits, I agree. However the original poster did not specify what the class in question is, so it could be anything, in which case you cannot generically state that it is safe to do this, it depends on the class in question.

Comment: @DanieleB: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: hi @ZygoteInit, yes I had read it, thanks. you and ci_ are saying pretty much the same thing. ci_ is adding that also not thread-safe objects might be troublesome

Answer (score 2):

The question is rather generic and there are a few parts to it, let's deal with them one at a time:

"Is it safe to run a [any] method of an `AsyncTask` class member [not further specified `Object`] inside `doInBackground`?"

Is it safe with regards to what?

"Is there a multithreading issue?"

Ok, so is it safe with regards to multithreading? The answer is no, it is not generally safe, unless you *know* this *particular* method on this *particular* object is safe to call from multiple threads. In other words, just by putting something into an `AsyncTask` doesn't make it safer than using any other `Thread`.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private void testLoop(String logTag, SimpleDateFormat sdf, String inputString) {
        Log.d(logTag, "Starting...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                String outputString;
                outputString = sdf.format(sdf.parse(inputString));
                if (!outputString.equals(inputString)) {
                    Log.d(logTag, "i: " + i + " inputString: " + inputString + " outputString: " + outputString);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(logTag, "Boom! i: " + i, e);
                break;
            }
        }
        Log.d(logTag, "Done!");
    }

    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf;
        public MyAsyncTask(SimpleDateFormat sdf) {
            this.sdf = sdf;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            testLoop("MyAsyncTask", sdf, "2014-12-24 12:34:56.789");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        new MyAsyncTask(sdf).execute();
        testLoop("MainActivity", sdf, "2015-04-01 23:23:23.232");
    }
}
```

Output:

> 08:52:37.462: D/MainActivity(13051): Starting...
>   08:52:37.466: D/MyAsyncTask(13051): Starting...
>   08:52:37.466: D/MainActivity(13051): i: 3 inputString: 2015-04-01 23:23:23.232 outputString: 2014-12-01 0012:34:23.789
>   08:52:37.467: D/MainActivity(13051): Done!
>   08:52:37.467: D/MyAsyncTask(13051): i: 0 inputString: 2014-12-24 12:34:56.789 outputString: 2014-12-01 12:34:23.789
>   08:52:37.467: D/MyAsyncTask(13051): Done!

Oh, something "weird" happened.

Let's run it again:

> 08:53:44.551: D/MainActivity(13286): Starting...
>   08:53:44.562: D/MyAsyncTask(13286): Starting...
>   08:53:44.563: D/MainActivity(13286): i: 11 inputString: 2015-04-01 23:23:23.232 outputString: 1970-01-24 12:00:23.232
>   08:53:44.563: D/MainActivity(13286): Done!
>   08:53:44.567: D/MyAsyncTask(13286): i: 0 inputString: 2014-12-24 12:34:56.789 outputString: 2014-01-24 12:34:56.789
>   08:53:44.567: D/MyAsyncTask(13286): Done!

Still weird, but different.

Let's run it one more time:

> 08:54:23.560: D/MainActivity(13286): Starting...
>   08:54:23.579: D/MyAsyncTask(13286): Starting...
>   08:54:23.596: D/MainActivity(13286): i: 3 inputString: 2015-04-01 23:23:23.232 outputString: 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
>   08:54:23.596: D/MainActivity(13286): Done!
>   08:54:24.423: D/MyAsyncTask(13286): Done!

Different again, this time it didn't even manifest itself in one of the threads.

Definitely a multithreading issue. How do we fix it?

From the question: "should you in doInBackground only access objects which have been deliberately passed"?

Well, let's try that, change the code around a bit:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<SimpleDateFormat, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(SimpleDateFormat... params) {
        testLoop("MyAsyncTask", params[0], "2014-12-24 12:34:56.789");
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(sdf);
    testLoop("MainActivity", sdf, "2015-04-01 23:23:23.232");
}
```

What happens when we run this?

> 09:11:43.734: D/MainActivity(15881): Starting...
>   09:11:43.763: D/MyAsyncTask(15881): Starting...
>   09:11:43.782: D/MainActivity(15881): i: 7 inputString: 2015-04-01 23:23:23.232 outputString: 2015-004-01 00:00:00.789
>   09:11:43.782: D/MainActivity(15881): Done!
>   09:11:43.783: D/MyAsyncTask(15881): i: 5 inputString: 2014-12-24 12:34:56.789 outputString: 2014-012-24 12:34:56.789
>   09:11:43.783: D/MyAsyncTask(15881): Done!

Wow, still weird. So it looks like the `AsyncTask` doesn't even protect us if we pass our `Object` as a parameter.

So what does it protect us from? The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) state:

> AsyncTask guarantees that all callback calls are synchronized in such a way that the following operations are safe without explicit synchronizations.
>   - Set member fields in the constructor or onPreExecute(), and refer to them in doInBackground(Params...).
>   - Set member fields in doInBackground(Params...), and refer to them in onProgressUpdate(Progress...) and onPostExecute(Result).

That's all it does, no blank cheque.

So how can we fix it then?

There are a number of options. In this particular contrived example, the obvious choice is to not share `sdf` but create a new instance in the `AsyncTask`. That's usually a good option if possible. If not, you (the developer) have to make sure that access is somehow synchronized. For our example you could use a synchronized statement:

```
synchronized (sdf) {
    outputString = sdf.format(sdf.parse(inputString));
}
```

> 08:56:59.370: D/MainActivity(13876): Starting...
>   08:56:59.375: D/MyAsyncTask(13876): Starting...
>   08:57:00.287: D/MainActivity(13876): Done!
>   08:57:01.216: D/MyAsyncTask(13876): Done!

Yay! Finally!

You could also synchronize the whole method:

```
private synchronized void testLoop(String logTag, SimpleDateFormat sdf, String inputString) {
    // ...
}
```

> 08:59:11.237: D/MainActivity(14361): Starting...
>   08:59:12.036: D/MainActivity(14361): Done!
>   08:59:12.036: D/MyAsyncTask(14361): Starting...
>   08:59:12.862: D/MyAsyncTask(14361): Done!

Still works, but now you have basically serialised all the work that we hoped to do in parallel with multiple threads. Not unsafe, but not good performance. Another pitfall of multithreaded programming, but not related to the question. (In fact the synchronized statement version above isn't a whole lot better performance wise, since we're not really doing anything else in our example anyway).

What about handlers?

From the question: "do you need to use a handler?"

Let's modify the example to use a `Handler`:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Handler, Void, Void> {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    public MyAsyncTask(SimpleDateFormat sdf) {
        this.sdf = sdf;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Handler... params) {
        params[0].post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                testLoop("MyAsyncTask", sdf, "2014-12-24 12:34:56.789");
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    new MyAsyncTask(sdf).execute(new Handler());
    testLoop("MainActivity3", sdf, "2015-04-01 23:23:23.232");
}
```

> 10:36:15.899: D/MainActivity(17932): Starting...
>   10:36:16.028: D/MainActivity(17932): Done!
>   10:36:16.038: D/MyAsyncTask(17932): Starting...
>   10:36:16.115: D/MyAsyncTask(17932): Done!

A `Handler` would work as well in this case (although the example starts to look very poor now), because it essentially removes multithreading issues for a particular piece of code by running it on the other thread altogether. That also means that this won't really work if you need to use a result of that piece of code in your `AsyncTask` immediately.

So what's all this talk about not using UI elements in `doInBackground()`?

New example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;

    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        TextView tv;
        public MyAsyncTask(TextView tv) {
            this.tv = tv;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            tv.setText("Boom!");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello world!");
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Click!");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new MyAsyncTask(tv).execute();
            }
        });
        layout.addView(tv);
        layout.addView(button);
        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

Run this, click the button, you're app will stop and you'll find the following stack trace in logcat:

> 11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922): Process: com.example.testsothreadsafe, PID: 23922
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6357)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:874)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6871)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4057)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3915)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3890)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at com.example.testsothreadsafe.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:22)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at com.example.testsothreadsafe.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   11:21:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(23922):    ... 4 more

Android specifically prevents you from manipulating the view hierarchy from another thread than the one that created it. But is any *access* prevented?

Change the example to:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.d("MyAsyncTask", tv.getText().toString());
    return null;
}
```

Click the button, the output will be:

> 11:25:20.950: D/MyAsyncTask(24329): Hello world!

It appears, some access is allowed.

So what's the message here? Multithreaded programming is tricky. Just because Android prevents you from doing some things, that doesn't mean anything it doesn't prevent you from doing is automatically "safe".

Comment: actually it is the case that mObjA is accessed from multiple threads

Comment: Then it depends on whether mObjA itself is threadsafe or not, this cannot be answered generically, for example SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe (many people don't know this)

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncTask is thread safe. But I guess it is more convenient to just use the generic nature of `AsyncTask`. That way you can get away with just making anonymous inner classes.

```
new AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void>() {

    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params){
        params[0].aMethod();
        return null;
    }
}.execute(obj);
```

But like others are saying, the object you pass in **might not** be thread safe.

Comment: I was merely referring to the AsyncTask itself. Updated my answer to reflect this.