# Data appears before onPostExecute fired

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the next strange problem, I'm trying to parse response with JSON data in background, because there's a lot of data and call it like this:

```
protected AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Void> createParseTask() {

    return new AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject... jsonObjects) {
            parseResponse(jsonObjects[0]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (!mEmpty) {
                if (swipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
                    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if(!mShowStored) {
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else if (mShowStored) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                internetError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          internetError.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.emptyRequestError));
            }

            if (!mShowStored) {
                checkData();
            }

        }
    };

}
```

And the parseResponse() method is written like this:

```
protected void parseResponse(JSONObject response) {

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    OrdersDatabase ordersDatabase = new OrdersDatabase(AppController.getAppContext());
    try {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppController.getAppContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        String dateTime = response.getString("serverDateTime");
        dateTime = dateTime.replace(":", "%3A");
        dateTime = dateTime.replace("+", "%2B");
        editor.putString("serverDateTime", dateTime);
        editor.apply();
        jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("updatedOrders");
        JSONArray active = response.getJSONArray("activeOrders");
        if (jsonArray.length() == 0 && active.length() == 0) {
            mEmpty = true;
        } else if (response.length() > 0 || jsonArray.length() > 0 && active.length() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(String.valueOf(jsonArray.get(i)));
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

                String orderID = jsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("id").getAsString();

                if (!mShowStored) {
                    if (!ordersDatabase.checkOrder(orderID)) {
                        ordersDatabase.addOrderData(jsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("id").getAsString(), String.valueOf(jsonObject));
                    } else {
                        ordersDatabase.updateOrderData(jsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("id").getAsString(), String.valueOf(jsonObject));
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < active.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = active.getJSONObject(i);
                String activeOrder = jsonObject.getString("id");
                activeOrders.add(activeOrder);
                if (ordersDatabase.checkOrder(activeOrder)) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(activeOrder)) {
                        JsonObject jsonOrder = (JsonObject) parser.parse(ordersDatabase.getOrderData(activeOrder));
                        cityList.add(OrderData.fromJson(jsonOrder));
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So I don't know how, but somehow the data appeared in RecyclerView is there before onPostExecute is shown, because in post execute the progressbar should go invisible and `notifydatasetchange` should also appear there. But data appears before the progressbar goes invisible and `notifyDataSetChange()` fired, help me please!

Comment: It's a little unclear what the issue is. `onPostExecute()` is never "shown" but called. What makes you think the RV is filled before that method is called?

Comment: @codeMagic because in post execute the progressbar should go invisible and notifydatasetchange should also appear there. But data appears before the progressbar goes invisible and `notifyDataSetChange()` fired.

Comment: Remove super.onPostExecute call.

Comment: @greenapps `super.onPostExecute()` does nothing.

Comment: 'mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);'. Use mProgressBar.dismiss(); instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the privilege to comment, so I'll post it here:
You don't happen to have listeners on your `ordersDatabase`, `cityList` or `activeOrders`?

Comment: I guess no, 'cause I thought I don't actually need those listeners.

Comment: I would recommend debugging through the `parseResponse` method and finding out, at which line exactly the UI is being updated.

Comment: I've done that already, but got nothing which will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

An `AsyncTask` that returns nothing from `doInBackground()` (and doesn't communicate with `onPostExecute()` via private members) is always suspicious.

You have a lot of side effects in your `AsyncTask` and that kind of stuff is hard to debug. You add to `cityList` and `activeOrders` for example, without showing what that actually is. Presumably those are lists attached to some `Adapter` and adding to those might trigger a `View` attached to the `Adapter` to be re-drawn. If that is the case you could try calling `setNotifyOnChange(false)` on `mAdapter` (to delay updates until you manually call `notifyDataSetChanged()` later).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setNotifyOnChange(boolean)

In general, if your `AsyncTask` doesn't return anything or otherwise "communicate" with `onPostExecute()` there is little point in having `onPostExecute()` in the first place. Even better would be not to have any side effect in `doInBackground()` and instead return the parsed data and only add it to `cityList` and `activeOrders` in `onPostExecute()`.

Multi-threading is tricky and `AsyncTask`s while appearing/attempting to make it easier, have many pitfalls. I have attempted to answer a question on thread safety of `AsyncTask` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902941/android-can-you-access-asynctask-class-members-in-doinbackground/28903094#28903094)

Comment: `citylist` and `activOrders` are ArrayLists, yes. 
Problem is I'm not using ArrayAdapter, I'm using `RecyclerView.Adapter` and it has no `setNotifyOnChange(false)`.

Comment: Can you show where and how exactly you are using `citylist` and `activeOrders`?